# Have one folder with files that have the same name but different file

Tags: linux, bash

i am trying to copy only original files from one directory to another, but some files have the same name... i am trying to use hash to compare files, if its not in directory send it there and if the name is the same change it to file_name.something. at this time im getting some files and the files that have the same name are being overwritten... can anyone suggest something?

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

source_folder=$1
destination_folder=$2

if [ $# -eq 0 ] 
then 
    echo "usage:$0 directory_name";exit 999; 
fi

if [ -d $source_folder ]
then
     echo "source source_folder exists."
else
     echo "Source folder doesn't exist"
     exit 1;
fi

if [ -d $destination_folder ]
then
    echo "Destination folder exists"
else
    mkdir $destination_folder
fi



find "$source_folder" -name "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -exec ./check {} $destination_folder/ \;





 #!/bin/bash -xv

file=$1
destination_folder=$2
file_hash=`md5sum "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

for a in $destination_folder/*
do
   curr_hash=$(md5sum "$a" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
   curr_file=$a

   if [ ! "$file_hash" == "$curr_hash" ]; 
   then
   if [[ -f $destination_folder/$file ]] ;
   then # CAN ANYBODY TELL ME WHY IT IGNORES THIS LINE
      cp "$file" "$file.JPG"
      mv "$file.JPG" "$destintion_folder" 
     else # IT GOES STRAIGHT FOR THIS ONE
       cp "$file" "$destination_folder"
   fi
   fi

done
```

Comment: Note that return code are bytes so 999 is out or range. It will be returned as 231.

Comment: You are missing a closing `]` in your `if` statement in your second script

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? have you tried Rsync?

Comment: no, is it simpler to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if [ "$file_hash" == "$a" ];` compares a hash with a filename. You need something like

```
if [ "$file_hash" == $(md5sum "$a" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ];
```

to compute the hash for each of the file in destination folder.

Furthermore, your for loop, in its current version, runs only once ; you need something like

```
for a in $destination_folder/*
```

to get all files in that folder rather than just the folder name.

Based on your edits, a solution would look like

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

file=$1
destination_folder=$2
file_hash=`md5sum "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

# test that the filename exists in the destination dir
if [[ -f $destination_folder/$file ]] ; then
    dest_hash=$(md5sum "$destination_folder/$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    # test that the hash is the same
    if [[ "$file_hash" == $curr_hash ]] ; then
        cp "$file.JPG" "$destination_folder/$file.JPG"
    else 
        # do nothing
    fi
else
    # destination does not exit, copy file
    cp "$file.JPG" "$destination_folder/$file"
fi
```

This does not ensure that there are no duplicates. It simply ensures that distinct files with identical names do not overwrite each other.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

file=$1
destination_folder=$2
file_hash=`md5sum "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

# test each file in destination
for a in $destination_folder/*
do
   curr_hash=$(md5sum "$a" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
   if [ "$file_hash" == $curr_hash ]; 
   then
       # an identical file exists. (maybe under another name)
       # do nothing
       exists=1
       break
   fi
done

if [[ $exists != 1 ]] ; then
   if [[ -f $destination_folder/$file ]] ; then
       cp "$file.JPG" "$destination_folder/$file.JPG"
   else 
       cp "$file.JPG" "$destination_folder"
   fi
fi
```

Not tested.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, now it only copied all the files twice, the duplicates have the extra .JPG :s btw i dont know it this is important but the destination folder is empty

Comment: +1 to damienfrancois. @user2988983: you'll also probably need to do it in several steps:  **1)** compare the current $file and its $file_hash  with **every** files in the directory [even just-copie-over ones? or not, depending on what you need to], and see if it is "already there". And **if it is NOT** already there : **2)** copy it over (changing its name if it happens that there is a file  already present (maybe with a different hash!) with the same name). That way only $file with a "new hash" will be copied over. Not sure that's what you meant, but it's what you asked for ^^

Comment: @OlivierDulac thanks for the `+1` but I'd rather you clicked on the up arrow next to my answer :)

Comment: @damienfrancois: indeed, i forgot ^^ sorry... i'm quite tired today :p

Comment: @damienfrancois: based on his comment and  need (copy files from 1 dir to another, and the "another" starts empty) I guess it's in need of a revamp... something like `move.sh  original_dir  destination_dir` script witch does something like `for origfile in $(find "$1" -type f) ; do hash_not_already_present_in_destdir "$origfile" "$2/" && mv_with_renaming_if_needed "$origfile" "$2/" ; done`

Comment: basicaly i have 2 scripts, one that makes sure that source and destination folders exist and what kind of file i need from the source, and then execute the other script that i have showed here.

Comment: #!/bin/bash -xv

source_folder=$1
destination_folder=$2

if [ $# -eq 0 ] 
then 
    echo "usage:$0 directory_name";exit 999; 
fi

if [ -d $source_folder ]
then
     echo "source source_folder exists."
else
     echo "Source folder doesn't exist"
     exit 1;
fi

if [ -d $destination_folder ]
then
    echo "Destination folder exists"
else
    mkdir $destination_folder
fi



find "$source_folder" -name "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -exec ./check {} $destination_folder/ \;

Comment: #!/bin/bash -xv

file=$1
destination_folder=$2
file_hash=`md5sum "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

for a in $destination_folder/*
do
   if [ "$file_hash" == $(md5sum "$a" | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ; 
   then
       cp "$file" "$destination_folder"
       
   else
       cp "$file" "$file.JPG"
       mv "$file.JPG" "$destination_folder"
   fi
done

Comment: i am assuming that the best way to copy original files even with the same name is to compare their hash since i think that is the only thing that i can guaranty its original

Comment: Please update your question with your scripts. They are impossible to read as comments. Also, if you could provide with a 'before' / 'after' comparison with 3 files, it would help.

Comment: 'if the name is the same change it' I am not sure I understand that. In which case exactly does it have to be renamed? (the name of what the same as what?)

Comment: meanin i have a IMG_1234.JPG with a specific hash, and another IMG_1234.JPG with a different hash, change the name of the second to IMG_1234.JPG.JPG

Comment: and if you find an IMG_3214.JPG with the same hash as IMG_1234.JPG, what should happen?

Comment: well im not sure because i am using the hash as a unique identifier of the pictures. so even if the name changes, the hash will not. i am assuming