# Find and copy, rename files with same name

Tags: bash, find

I have this find

```
find "$source_folder" -name "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" -exec cp {} $destination_folder \;
```

i want only the IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG, in the source folder there are diferent files with same name,and same files with same name, how can i copy everything and rename all the same name files with extra .JPG without deleting any unique files?
PS: noob, please could you explain so i can try and learn

Comment: Not sure `find` is up to it... maybe you're better off with a python script.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961306/have-one-folder-with-files-that-have-the-same-name-but-different-file/19961492#19961492

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that your file names don't contain any whitespace. It makes things easier.

You can pipe the output of the find command to a loop where you can run some tests whether or not you want to copy the file.

I have to determine the name of the file and where it is copied to. In order to do that, I have to strip off the `$source_folder` from the name of the file I find, and prepend the name of the `$dest_folder`. This is where I want to actually copy the file.

Your directions are a bit confusing. I am assuming you're doing the copy if the `$dest_file` doesn't exist or it is different from the source. Once I determine that this is the file you want me to copy, I have to make sure the destination directory exists, and if it doesn't I create it. Now, I can do my copy.

I have two `echo` statements in here. This way, you can do a *dry run* of this script to make sure it's doing what you want it to do. If it looks good, you can remove the `echo` commands from the two lines and rerun the script.

```
find "$source_folder" -name "IMG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG" | while read file_name
do
     rootname=${file_name#$source_folder/}  # Removes the source folder from the name
     dest_name="${dest_folder}/$rootname"

     if [ ! -e "$dest_name" ] || [ ! diff "$file_name" "$dest_name" > /dev/null 2>&1 ]
     then
        $dest_folder=$(basename $dest_name)
        [ ! -d "$dest_folder" ] && echo mkdir -p "$dest_folder" #Remove echo if it works
        echo cp "$file_name" "$dest_name"   #Remove 'echo' if it works
     fi
done
```