# Including different files with the same name in a Find and Move Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, mv

Im using a bash script to search for and archive files in different sub directories. There are some files that have the same name;

(e.g. ABC_000.gif)

however they are in fact different images. Is there a simple way to move and rename these files by adding a string to the end of the filename such as ABC_000.gif for the original file and ABC_000.gif.gif for the duplicated file

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961306/have-one-folder-with-files-that-have-the-same-name-but-different-file ?

Comment: Why not prefix each filename with their original directory name in your find command to make them unique.

Answer (score 1):

`$SOURCE` is the source file, `$DEST` is the destination file; this appends the suffix while `$DEST` is already there, then moves it.

```
while [ -e $DEST ]
do
    DEST+=.`<<<$DEST sed 's/.*\.//'`
done
mv $SOURCE $DEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
i = 0
FILES=`find -name ABC_000.gif | xargs -r`
for FILE in $FILES; do
    mv $FILE ./$FILE_$i
    let "i += 1"
done
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a mistake.