# BASH: Checking if files are duplicates within a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, duplicates

I am writing a house-keeping script and have files within a directory that I want to clean up.
I want to move files from a source directory to another, there are many sub-directories so there could be files that are the same. What I want to do, is either use CMP command or MD5sum each file, if they are no duplicates then move them, if they are the same only move 1.

So the I have the move part working correctly as follows:

```
find /path/to/source -name "IMAGE_*.JPG" -exec mv '{}' /path/to/destination \;
```

I am assuming that I will have to loop through my directory, so I am thinking.

for files in /path/to/source
do
if -name "IMAGE_*.JPG"
then
md5sum (or cmp) $files
...stuck here (I am worried about how this method will be able to compare all the files against eachother and how I would filter them out)...
then just do the mv to finish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961306/have-one-folder-with-files-that-have-the-same-name-but-different-file ?

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort | uniq -d
```

That'll spit out all the md5 hashes that have duplicates. then it's just a matter of figuring out which file(s) produced those duplicate hashes.

Comment: On macOS, try `find . -type f -exec md5 {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool designed for this purpose, it's [fdupes](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/) :

```
  fdupes -r dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

[dupmerge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dupmerge/) is another such tool...